# Word that means a situation where one person cannot describe something to another.

Tags: obscure-terms

For example - A situation such as "describe a color to a blind person". In this situation person A is not blind and can see the color "red". Person B is blind and has never seen red, so the person understands what red is but the person cannot relate to the "color Red".

I've heard the word before and it's an obscure word. I'm having a lethologica moment.

Thank you!

Comment: incommensurable-referring to the inability to compare two things due to different perceptions.

Comment: inexplicable-unable to be explained or accounted for.

Comment: "*describe a color to a sighted person*" is also problematic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few words that come to mind, but I am not sure they capture the exact meaning you are looking for.

The first is simply "indescribable", which cannot be described because it's too unusual or extreme. You can also try "undefinable", that is, not able to be defined or described exactly.

There is another word which means that you cannot speak about it: "ineffable". Similar words are "unfathomable" and "inexpressible".

Synonyms from inexpressible: indescribable, indefinable, unutterable, unspeakable, ineffable, beyond words, nameless; unimaginable, inconceivable, unthinkable, untold.

Answer (score 0):

It there is a story that cannot be narrated in the sense of told:
inenarrable

It is inenarrable. It is pretty obscure. It's used a lot in French.

Answer (score 0):

**Supersensory**

> From Latin super, over or beyond + sentire, to feel.
>
> 1.Beyond the range of what is perceptible by the senses; not belonging to the experienceable physical world. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supersensory))

If person B cannot experience something, like a color, then that is something that is beyond their ability to experience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you referred to the word 'qualia', which is the individual instances of subjective, conscious experience.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you add a definition from a reputable dictionary?